# An equivalent definition of limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f(h)$ be a real valued vanction such that $\lim_{h \to 0}f(h)=0$

Is it true that: $$\lim_{h \to 0}f(h)=0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{\delta \to 0^+}\sup_{|h|<\delta}f(h)=0$$

Comment: The right hand side of the $\iff$ is the limsup of $f$ and it is usually written $$\operatorname{limsup}_{h\to 0} f(h).$$ There's an analogous definition of liminf. A function admits limit at a point iff limsup equals liminf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really. For example, take $f(x)$ be $-1$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $0$ otherwise.

In this case the right hand side is true, but the limit doesn't actually exist.

Comment: I have seen some kinds of this techniques..can this be true under more assumptions? For instance if the function is non negative?

Comment: @MariosGretsas Yes, replace $f$ with $|f|$ on the RHS.

Comment: Is it true if the function is continuous ?

Comment: @MariosGretsas I think it is, because in that case the limit exists, and the limit would be equal to limit superior (and limit inferior as well) as long as it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt , correct me if wrong.

Partial answer.

Let $f$ be continuos.

1) $\Rightarrow:$

$\epsilon >0$ be given

There is a $\delta >0$ such that

$|h| < \delta$ implies $|f(h)-0| \lt \epsilon$.

With this  $\delta$ :

$\rightarrow$:

$|\sup (f(h))| \le \epsilon$.

2) $\Leftarrow:$

Since $f$ is continuos(assumption):

$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(h)$ $(=: L)$ exists.

Need to show that $L=0$.

Assume $L>0$.

Given $\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+} |\sup (f)|_{|h|<\delta}| =0$.

For $\epsilon >0$  there is a $\delta$ s.t .

$|h| \le \delta$ implies $|\sup f(h) -0| \lt \epsilon$.

Since $f$ continuos $f$ attains it's maximum in
$ [-\delta,\delta]$.

For $|h| \le \delta$:

$\sup(f(h))= f_{\max}(h) \ge L >0.$

A contradiction(choose $\epsilon =L/2$).

Case $L<0$,  consider $-f(x)$ to obtain a contradiction